# Is is possible to define memory and disk space for a Docker Container?

Tags: docker

Is is possible to define memory and disk space for a Docker Container?
Docker is replacement of Virtual Machines but I am confused about Docker's resource utilization. I can set the resources to be used by particular VM at the time of installation but Docker does not provide this facility so, I want to know how Docker uses resources from the host machine?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-cpu-and-memory

Answer (score 3):

The [Docker Reference for Runtime constraints on resources](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources) says:

```
-m, --memory=""     Memory limit (format: <number>[<unit>]). Number is a positive integer. Unit can be one of b, k, m, or g. Minimum is 4M.
--memory-swap=""    Total memory limit (memory + swap, format: <number>[<unit>]). Number is a positive integer. Unit can be one of b, k, m, or g.
--memory-reservation=""     Memory soft limit (format: <number>[<unit>]). Number is a positive integer. Unit can be one of b, k, m, or g.
--kernel-memory=""  Kernel memory limit (format: <number>[<unit>]). Number is a positive integer. Unit can be one of b, k, m, or g. Minimum is 4M.
```

and much more

Comment: Link is broken. New link - https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-constraints-on-resources

Answer (score -2):

Yes.

By default, containers (just like standard processes) can ask for all the system resources. However, you can start containers with fine-grained controls, limiting their resources and privileges.